# Is there a way to parse shortcodes in PHP?

Tags: php, shortcode, templates

Many plugins don't provide a documented way to access their functions from within PHP (e.g. when building a custom theme), but only shortcodes to insert in posts.

Is there a standard way of executing shortcode from within PHP as if it were part of the content? Like so (this is made up):

```
$gallery_html = execute_shortcode("{gallery}");  //  this would return the HTML  
                                                 //  that the gallery plugin returns
                                                 // in the context of the current post
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can execute shortcodes using the [do_shortcode()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode) function

```
$gallery_html = do_shortcode('[gallery]');
```

Comment: I somehow always misunderstood how this function works -  it's *that* easy. Thanks!